# Connecting to Redis Cluster from Spring Boot caching abstraction

Tags: spring-boot, caching, redis

I am using Spring Boot with Caching abstraction support to connect to redis-server for storing/fetching data for caching.

I use the below properties for connecting to redis-server.

```
spring.redis.host=localhost
spring.redis.port=6379
spring.redis.password=mypassword
spring.cache.type=redis
```

I am able to successfully connect to redis server and store/fetch data.

For high availability,it is decided to use 3 nodes , 1 master and 2 slave nodes for redis server.

In that case, I am not sure how to provide the configuration to connect to redis cluster from my spring boot application.

Are there any properties supported by spring boot to connect to redis cluster.

I am using out-of-box support of spring caching abstraction with support for annotation **@cacheable.**

I have the below 2 dependencies added to my pom.xml
**spring-boot-starter-cache** and **spring-boot-starter-data-redis**
and also using **spring boot 1.5.13.**

Is there support for connecting to redis cluster when using spring caching abstraction in spring boot.

Comment: Is the high availability setup going to use Redis sentinel? This setup would be documented here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-redis/docs/current/reference/html/#redis:sentinel

Comment: @Jbaur what approach did you went with?